# Can't ping server over VPN, from behind other VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, route

My local server is set up as both an OpenVPN server and client. Its client connects to another remote OpenVPN server (which I also administer). Both servers run Ubuntu Linux.

I then connect my laptop (running Ubuntu Linux) to the local OpenVPN server.

The topology looks like this:

```
remote-server: ww.xx.yy.zz
               VPN server: 10.8.2.1
               LAN: 192.168.1.0/24

local-server: aa.bb.cc.dd
              VPN client: 10.8.2.2
              VPN server: 10.6.0.1
              LAN: 192.168.3.0/24

laptop: VPN client: 10.6.0.10
```

From `local-server`, I can ping `10.8.2.1` and also anything in `192.168.1.0/24`.
Also, from `remote-serve`, I can ping `10.8.2.2` and also anything in `192.168.3.0/24`.

From `laptop`, I can ping `10.8.2.2` and also anything in `192.168.3.0/24`. But I can't ping `10.8.2.1` or anything in `192.168.1.0/24`. It just hangs.

I have tried temporarily setting all iptables policies on both servers to `ACCEPT`, with no luck.

What could the matter be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the routes for 10.8.2.0 or 192.168.1.0 published correctly for the laptop or is it using full tunnel mode (everything goes to the vpn server)?

What about the return packets have you verified that the remote server can route back to VPN-server subnet on the local-server?

Can you do a ping 192.168.1.1 from source 10.6.0.1 on the local-server?

Comment: It's using full tunnel mode on IPv4.

Comment: That was the issue after all. I added `route 10.6.0.0 255.255.0.0` to the remote server's configuration and it's all fine now. Great!